# How can I loop through entity reference values?

Tags: entities

My content type "Export" has an entity reference to the type "country" (i.e. you assign countries to the export). I wish to do something like the following

```
$countries = $node->field_exporter_countries['und'][0]['value'];

foreach ($countries as &$value) {
   print $value;
}
```

#### Edit

I also tried this. But i get the wrong titles back.

```
$nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($countries));
foreach ($nodes as $n) {
  print $n->title;
  print "<br /> ";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `entityreference_field_schema()` function, the column name for an entity reference field is `target_id` (not `value`). That said, to extract the node ids you should probably use something like this:

```
$nids = array();
foreach ($node->field_exporter_countries[$node->language] as $index => $item) {
  $nids[] = $item['target_id'];
}

$nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);

// etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Drupal in front of me at the moment so this is pure guestimation, but I think you're actually looking at doing something like the following:

```
$countries = $node->field_exporter_countries[$node->language];

foreach ($countries as $key => $data) {
  print $data['value'];
}
```

Note that I've used `$node->language` instead of `und` as a personal preference, but there are other benefits.

Comment: thanks, i tried you loop but i get not results. I also tried to cast it to node but i get the wrong drupal pages. See above

Comment: to clarify. if i go count($countries) i get results. So there is data there.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you have a field, and you want to format its output a certain way, you implement a field formatter.

And if you do implement a new field formatter, Drupal will call [`hook_field_formatter_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) for you, with `$items` as a handy array to turn into a renderable array.

Comment: I don't think the OP ever mentioned *displaying* fields.  A field formatter would be relatively useless if you want to manipulate the data in code.

Comment: It does kinda say "print($value);" doesn't it? :-)